# Can I install a WordPress site locally from a tar.gz file?

Tags: installation

I need to view a website that was previously hosted via SiteGround (WordPress/cPanel). I cannot view it because there is no longer a domain associated. I created a backup, which produced a tar.gz file. I also downloaded the public folder as a zip (has wp-content, wp-includes, etc).

I am redesigning the site, but I need to be able to view these old pages/content.

Comment: If the backup includes the WordPress files as well as the database, in theory yes you should be able to recreate the site locally. You'll need to set up a local server environment to actually "host" the website locally ([MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) would be a good option for that as it's free and relatively easy to use).

Answer (score 1):

> Can I install a WordPress site locally from a `.tar.gz` file?

This likely depends entirely on the contents of the archive. `.tar.gz` is just a compression format. You will have to extract it to have any website work correctly but otherwise the particular storage format has no bearing on your question.

> I created a backup, which produced a `.tar.gz` file. I also downloaded the public folder as a zip (has wp-content, wp-includes, etc).

Wordpress typically requires a database to run. You don't mention whether or not you have a backup of this, but if you don't, you may run into issues.

> I am redesigning the site, but I need to be able to view these old pages/content.

In theory it's possible to reproduce a site locally. But dynamic sites like those produced with Wordpress may be more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I created a little guide I made on how to restore your WordPress site from a .tar.gz backup, without the need for any database, etc. changes to your config files. Maybe it can help someone...

https://youtu.be/F84btYZx8Lc

Answer (score 0):

- Make a dump from the database
- Download the tar.gz file

**

- Import the database
- Upload tar to new host